# Possible to query for data in multiple keys in the same query?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I'm trying to lookup some data in my database using a string, but utilizing multiple json keys to check in.

I know you can lookup using a single key in this case 'name'

```
SELECT * 
FROM products_product 
WHERE data->>'name' IN ('Value 1', 'Value 2')
```

My issue is that i have two types of json values being saved and therefore need to check both 'name' and 'title'

As an example to simplify it:

```
{
  "name": "Value 1"
}
```

while the second maybe looking like this:

```
{
  "title": "Value 2"
}
```

How can i do a single query check both 'name' and 'title' for the values i got?

I was expecting maybe to be able to do something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM products_product 
WHERE data->>('name', 'title') IN ('Value 1', 'Value 2')
```

But its not possible!

Would want to avoid having to do multiple queries as i know the keys the data can be placed in and got them as a list or tuple (whatever is needed)

So my final question is:

How can i query the database to check multiple fields (if they exist) for the values i have defined?

I'm expecting both the examples to be returned in a single query and not just one of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `OR`

```
SELECT * 
FROM products_product 
WHERE data->>'name' IN ('Value 1', 'Value 2')
   OR data->>'title' IN ('Value 1', 'Value 2')
```

You can slightly simplify this, by only specifying the values once:

```
with input (val) as (
  values ('Value1'), ('Value2') --<< note the parentheses!
)
SELECT * 
FROM products_product 
WHERE data->>'name' IN (select val from input)
   OR data->>'title' IN (select val from input)
```

Comment: Yea so i can add X amounts of OR ? - the two are just examples, i might have a list of 4 or a list of 10

Comment: @SteffenMandrup: this sounds like a strange design to begin with. But yes, if you don't know the structure of your data, then you need to prepare for all possible combinations which means your query will get ugly.

Comment: There is logic behind it all - we can simply just save some various input. I know all the places the data can be, just had to be sure i can find them all!

Seems to work - amazing a simple OR could solve this (and that i didnt think about it lol)

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what version you are using.  You can do this with json path in postgres 12.  The syntax is a bit obtuse, but it's possible:

```
SELECT * FROM products_product 
WHERE jsonb_path_exists(data, 
  'strict $.keyvalue() ? ((@.value == "Value 1" || @.value == "Value 2") && (@.key == "name" || @.key == "title"))');
```

This will search every key/value combo at the root of your object and look for keys equalling `name` or `title` and values equalling `Value 1` or `Value 2`.